# Stopping push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a app which has push notification in it.I have implemented it but my problem is I want to receive the notifications only when the user is signed-in to the app.
Something like the iPhone email application.
Any ideas how can I proceed for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove stored push device token from your APNS provider when user signs out of your app.

Comment: Or add a field to your APNs server to enable/disable notifications instead of purging records.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the device token gets stored.I guess its on the Provider side,somewhere in the .cer files.
And with both the answers I got idea that on client side I cannot prevent it,its all on the provider side.Correct?

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal: You receive push device token on client side in `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken`, and you decide how to store it on your server side.

Comment: @AndreyZ:-Certainly,this was a foolish question.I totally missed out this thing.
Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal accept the answer if you found your solution in it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop or limit Push Notifications in any way **once they are sent**.

As long as:

(1) the user has your app installed, AND

(2) they agreed to allow push notifications on first run, AND

(3) the device is on

then (if you send them a push), they will get a push notification regardless of whether or not your app is active, in the background or not running at all.

If device is off, they will get one when they turn the device back on (assuming (1) and (2) above are still true).

Note that Push Notifications are NOT guaranteed to be delivered, so you should not use them for sending important/critical information.

Instead of Push, you will probably want to implement something proprietary on your server where the device connects to your server and checks for messages everytime they start the app.